# Trigger activation control for actual afterUpdate

Tags: trigger, update, after

Here's a problem I'm wondering about how to solve, and have an elegant solution to for my future reference.   I have a callout to an external web service in my afterUpdate Opportunity trigger that runs on after Update.  The problem is that it is running immediately after insert since it's triggered by workflow rules that run after the opportunity is created.  These workflow rules update the opportunity and that triggers the afterUpdate trigger code.  What is an elegant way to solve this?  I don't want to run this in a batch since this won't ever be batch of size > 3 or 4 at max.  And my callout code is already bulkified as it is.

Would a createdDate <-> LastmodifiedDate comparison be the most effective way? I.e. if lastModifiedDate is at least 5-10-15-whatever minutes after createdDate then the callout will be invoked, else not?

Comment: You can modify Opportunity in before insert trigger same as it is updated by Workflow. This will not allow your workflow to update the opportunity when it is created and afterUpdate Opportunity trigger will not fire.

Comment: That's not my question, nor my problem.  My problem is that I want to prevent the trigger from executing the callout if the opportunity is under 5 minutes old or so (by that time all updates on the opportunity that happen on after insert should have finished and the triggering update should be a 'true' update, i.e. something that a true user is doing, not automated).

Comment: Yes in your case ` createdDate <-> LastmodifiedDate comparison` is best. It will solve your issue. Also a better approach is keep this time difference in Custom Setting so if in future if you want to change then you can change easily.